# Black Outline and Visible Faces in Cycles Render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, shadows

Previewing in Eevee looks fine, but when I switch to Cycles, this occurs:

[image: Left: Eevee render; Right: Cycles render of same]
Also comes as a white grain on the side opposite from the lightsource.
[image]

As you can see, parts become darker; there's black, ink-like stuff on the model (I thought it was AO at first and disabled it, but it's still there); and the faces of the model can be seen, especially along the chest and R-Leg.

The material setup is just the default BSDF with a Base Color (.jpg) and Normal map (.png) (fed through Mormal Map node).

Neither have been exported as an image, just rendered in the viewport.

Any advice appreciated - first day on Blender (well, near enough)

**-edit-**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like problem with normal maps. Try switching to non-color color space in texture node and use bump node instead of connecting normal map directly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't appear to change things. [see new image]

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 objects on the same spot. Take a look, right is one cube, left is 2 cubes in same position:

[image]